# Can't get Laravel registration form to store passwords with a hash

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-4, password-protection

Laravel stores the username and email ok, but doesn't save anything for the password field when I add the hash function. My controller code:

```
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::only(['username','email','password' => Hash::make('password')]);

    $newUser = User::create($data);

    if($newUser)
    {
        Auth::login($newUser);
        return Redirect::route('profile');
    }
    return Redirect::route('user.create')->withInput();
}
```

With this code the database field for password is simply left blank after registering a new user. Plaintext password inserts ok once I remove the hash function. Passwords need to be stored in a hashed form after users submit their info. When I seed the database with artisan, the hash function works fine, but not when I use it in controller logic. Can someone help please?

**EDIT:** In User.php

```
protected $fillable = ['username','email','password'];
```

Comment: do you have `$fillable` or `$guarded` properties defined on the User model?

Comment: what is the length of your password database column?

Comment: @watcher varchar(255)

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4.2? If so, are you also using the `RemindableTrait` and have a nullable `remember_token` column in your database schema?  I'm running out of questions to ask here... :(

Comment: @watcher Yes I have all those things (running 4.2 btw). I'm following [this](http://www.lswebapps.com/2014/06/15/laravel-login-registration-system-bootstrapping-installing-laravel/) tutorial. It covers hashing the fake seeds but not input from the actual form :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so besides the fact that the code you have above won't work, you're going about this the wrong way.

Firstly, the method you're trying to do would be:

```
$input = Input::only(['username', 'email', 'password']);
$input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
```

The approach you have of setting the value in only won't work, and besides that, you have `Hash::make('password')` which will make a hash of 'password' every time, not the variable, but the word. `Input::only()` accepts an array of field names to return, so it uses the values of the array, not the key. The array `['password' => Hash::make('password')]` has the value of the hash of the word password, not 'password'.

The best approach would be like this:

```
$input = Input::only(['username', 'email', 'password']);
$user = User::create($input);
```

Then, within your `User` model you have:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

This means that you don't have to bother with hashing, and can trust that the model will do it for you.

Also, if memory serves, `Auth::login()` accepts an integer, not a model, so it'd be `Auth::login($newUser->id)` to login the user who just registered, although I would highly recommend some sort of validation/activation via email.

Comment: Thanks, the model approach worked well. Email validation is in the works. That ACL tutorial on your site is helpful as well.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help, if you need anything else, try #laravel on irc.esper.net :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've missed this ```public function setPasswordAttribute($value)``` :)

Comment: For Laravel-beginners like me :) please note to use `$this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);` and not `$this->password = Hash::make($value);`

Comment: Aha yes! That'll create an infinite loop otherwise :P